# How do we assign the URL to the respective image which is randomly appearing?

Tags: jquery, random

The aim is to assign the respective URL to the respective image which is randomly appearing every 1 second on a web page in J Query.

so was wondering how do i combine both random items together? I probably did the wrong way of combining them by concatenation. hope to get some help here!

```
<script>
var img_arr = ["adidas_logo.jpg", "apple_logo.jpg","Changi_airport.jpg","starbucks.jpg"]

var links_arr =["https://www.adidas.com.sg/" , "https://www.apple.com/sg/" , "https://www.changiairport.com/","https://www.starbucks.com.sg/"]

var current = 0;
var current1 = 0;

setInterval(function()
{   
    var pic = Math.floor(Math.random()*img_arr.length);
    var links = Math.floor(Math.random()*links_arr.length);

    $("#image_slider").attr("src",img_arr[pic] +" "+ links_arr[links]);

    current = (img_arr[pic]< img_arr.length -1)? img_arr[pic] + 1 : 0;
    current1 = (img_arr[pic]< img_arr.length -1)? links_arr[links] + 1 : 0;

},1000);

</script>
```

the expected output is the random images displayed when clicked , it will go to the correct URL.
currently my error is it is random but the img src and URL are combined so the image doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the title of the image and src together.
Change this

```
 $("#image_slider").attr("src",img_arr[pic] +" "+ links_arr[links]);
```

to

```
 $("#image_slider").attr({"alt": img_arr[pic], "src": links_arr[links]+img_arr[pic]});
```

Here `links_arr[links]+img_arr[pic]` is your url.

Comment: It kind of solves the problem but my image doesn't come out and the link is not assigned to the right image when I checked the developer tools in my browser though.

Comment: From the code you provided this was the only error.

Comment: Could you please check the `links_arr` variable ? This contains all urls. Is all urls right ? I mean `https://www.adidas.com.sg/` correct or typo ? Does it mean `"https://www.adidas.com/sg/` ?

Comment: Oh I need to double check my code again cause the links does go to the website. The one on the Adidas you said both versions works LOL

Comment: I don't know about matching the pic as the logic is yours. So if my answer was hlepful, please consider upvoting or mark it answer

Comment: the images randomly appears from my img_arr and each image has to link a specific website or URL. Thats why i had to match.